# git pull and merge in automated build

Tags: git

I have an automation build script. Now, if there is any modified files in the git branch local, I stash it, then I do git checkout . But, based on the present branch, it may not be possible to pull the branch to be deployed as it asks for merge.
So, the code part is like this:

```
if [[ "git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no" ]]; then
    d=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
    commit_message="stash before release build date:${d}"
    git stash push -m "${commit_message}"
fi
git checkout ${branch}
retVal=$?
if [ $retVal -ne 0 ]; then
    exit 1
fi
git pull
<build code>
```

But the problem is, while running this script, it hangs. My most probable guess is, its unable to do automatic git pull after changing branches. Any inputs will be appreciated.

I really cannot think of scenario when default merge in git pull wouldn't be successful.

my scenario is this:
I am in branch 'A'. I stashed any modified changes. I want to checkout branch 'B'. I will update from origin. Then the build script runs.

Thanks and Regards,
Sudip

Comment: How does `git checkout` want to _merge_ anything? Can you post the error/warning/question you get?

Comment: The checkout might fail if you have **unversioned files** that would be overwritten by the checkout. Unversioned files are not saved in a stash (in fact you don't even check for them in your `if`-statement).

Comment: I think its in git pull. didnt realise it might arise, cause in scenario 1: we are in branch 'A'. Now before changing, I am stashing the modified changes. Now, I checkout branch 'B' and then do a git pull(from origin). I am not sure on which condition it will merge. Still, if that is the case, can i do that automatically? I am trying to replicate and see.

Comment: If the problem is in `git pull` you might want to edit your question as it specifically asks about `git checkout`, even in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I really cannot think of scenario when default merge in git pull wouldn't be successful.

It could fail if the remote branch was rebased.

I understand you want to checkout (and then build) some branch as it is in a remote repository. In that case don't do a `checkout` and `pull` but rather a `fetch` and `checkout`:

- `git fetch origin A`
- `git checkout origin/A` (ignore the warning about the detached HEAD)

That way you can even build branches that don't exist in your local repo. And you do not run into problems if the branch was rebased and pushed to the remote and therefore does not merge into your local branch (remember: `pull` is basically just a shortcut for `fetch` and `merge`).

Comment: thanks a lot, I undertand what you are saying, detached head state is not a problem, but would like to avoid if possible. Any means of doing that?

Comment: Yes, you can `git checkout -B A --track origin/A` which will create the local branch `A` if it does not exist yet. If the local branch `A` already exists it is [reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset). Either way you end up with a checked out local branch instead of a "detached HEAD".